# Raise HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable when import SeqVecEmbedder from bio_embeddings.embed

Tags: python

I am trying to process protein sequence by using bio_embeddings, but it raise "HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable" when import SeqVecEmbedder from bio_embeddings.embed.

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\bio_e\lib\site-packages\bio_embeddings\embed\__init__.py", line 31, in __init__
    get_model_file(path=f.name, model='seqvecv{}'.format(str(kwargs.get('seqvec_version', 1))), file=file)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\bio_e\lib\site-packages\bio_embeddings\utilities\remote_file_retriever.py", line 72, in get_model_file
    request.urlretrieve(url, filename=path, reporthook=t.update_to)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\bio_e\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\bio_e\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\bio_e\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\bio_e\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\bio_e\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\bio_e\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\bio_e\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 406: Not Acceptable
```

That is my code

```
from bio_embeddings.embed import SeqVecEmbedder
import torch 

seq = 'MVTYDFGSDEMHD'

embedder = SeqVecEmbedder()
embedding = embedder.embed(seq)
```

I am trying to use Bio_embeddings to process protein sequence.

Comment: I also have this problem. Have you made any progress?

Comment: Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/sacdallago/bio_embeddings/issues/156